# using John the Ripper to recover RAR password

Tags: macos, rar, password-recovery, xargs

Testing John the Ripper in Mac OS X as a RAR password recovery solution, but xargs gives me an error:

```
john --incremental:all --stdout | xargs -I jtr unrar e -pjtr -inul test2.rar | grep 100%
xargs: unterminated quote
```

But when I add '-0' to xargs to deal with the quote, I get another xargs error:

```
john --incremental:all --stdout | xargs -0 -I jtr unrar e -pjtr -inul test2.rar | grep 100%
xargs: insufficient space for argument
```

Which I suppose is because the '-0' is preventing xargs from using newlines as delimiters, which is creating the space issue?

Any ideas on how to make xargs happy?  Is there a way to solve the quotes issue while keeping the newline delimiter intact?

Comment: xargs launches ONE instance of your command with too many arguments, you need to launch unrar for each password you want to try like explained by @Mattias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do something like this instead:

```
john --incremental:all -stdout | while read pass;do
  rar x -p"${pass}" test2.rar
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then
    exit 0
  fi
done
```

Replace rar options, etc. as you like. This way the command only runs until it successfully unpacks the file and you don't have to grep for something. `$?` is a shell variable containing the return code of the last run command, and if run successfully it equals 0. So if you match it with 0 you know the previous command "worked".

**Edit 1**: Added "'s around the password, like `-p"${pass}"`.

Comment: This also asks for a password (will not be echoed) immediately followed by a reenter request partway through.  I wonder if that's john or unrar?

Comment: I tried this with a dummy password protected rar file, it matched the 25th password and it worked just fine. Use rar and not unrar to be sure, and type =exactly= as above, don't change rar for unrar, etc. Don't change variable names or anything.

Comment: If I wanted to restore a previous aborted session, would I just substitute "--incremental:all" with "--restore"?

Comment: Should work fine, yes!

Comment: The homebrew package manager has unrar but not rar -- what was the reason to use rar and not unrar?

Comment: The reason was simply that rar worked for me in my example, and you said that unrar didn't work for you. unrar should work pretty much the same way, so if you get it to work and won't have to install rar, all good! :) No other reason than that!

Comment: If I set MinLen and MaxLen to 1 in john.conf, and add "<echo 'pass is ['${pass}']'" before the unrar line, it does a bunch of letters, and then after "pass is [z]" and before "pass is [!], there is "pass is []" and it stops with the prompt "Enter password" -- is it echoing correctly that the pass is nothing?

Comment: If john sends out a totally empty string it will fail like that, yes. If john sends out a space it should work, but you MIGHT have to modify the line to read like this to cover spaces or words including spaces, if john generates those: `rar x -p"${pass}" test2.rar`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way (other than `-0` mode) to get xargs to ignore quotes in its input, but it's easy to use tr to convert the newlines to nulls and then use `-0` mode:

john --incremental:all --stdout | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -I jtr unrar e -pjtr -inul test2.rar | grep 100%

Comment: When I add the tr portion, it does this at the end: 

Enter password (will not be echoed):

Reenter password:

I guess that's rar asking?  I dunno.

Comment: I think that's what it does with the argument "-p" (i.e. when given the empty string as a password).  If I'm right, you should be able to suppress this by creating a john.conf file with "MinLen = 1".

Comment: Yeah it was set to = 0.  Weird.